# Horizontal Scalability with Drools

Tags: drools, scalability, rule-engine, kie, drools-fusion

Knowing that drools work with in memory data. Is there a way to distribute horizontally on different drools instances to enhance performance when performing CRUD operations on rules, fact types, etc? I guess the instances would need to be on sync with each other in some way, so they all have the same data in memory or share in some way a knowledge base. I'm kinda new on drools and trying to research on a way to move a monolith on a cloud environment (gcp) so it can take advantage on load balancing, scaling, etc. Want to know if there is any feature on drools itself that supports this or if there is any way to implement this myself, thanks in advance for any information/documentation/use case on this matter.

Currently I haven't tried a way to do this, but my goal is to improve performance and availability by using automatic scaling or support multiple instances of my app.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what kind of "CRUD" you're doing on Drools (or how). But if you just want to deploy new rules (for example), then this is identical to pushing any data or application changes to your deployment in a distributed system -- either your nodes are gradually updated, so during the upgrade process you have some mix of old and new logic/code; or you deploy new instances with the new logic/code and then transition traffic to your new instances and away from the old ones -- either all at once or in a controlled blue/green (or similar) fashion.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split a monolith, I think the best approach for you would be to consider Kogito [1] and microservice architecture. With microservices, you could even consider using the Function as a service approach - having small immutable service instances, that are just executed and disposed. Kogito mainly targets Quarkus platform, but there are also some Spring Boot examples. There is also OpenShift operator available.

As far as sharing the working memory, there was a project in the KIE community called HACEP [2]. Unfortunately that is now deprecated and we are researching other solutions to make the working memory persisted.

[1] https://kogito.kie.org/
[2] https://github.com/kiegroup/openshift-drools-hacep

Answer (score 0):

The term "[entry point](https://docs.drools.org/8.31.0.Final/drools-docs/docs-website/drools/rule-engine/index.html#cep-event-streams-con_rule-engine)" is related to the fact that we have multiple partitions in a Working Memory and you can choose which one you are inserting into. If you can organize your business logic to work with different entry points you can process 'logical partitions' on different machines in parallel safely. At a glance drools entry points gives you something like table partitioning in Oracle which implies the same options.

Answer (score 0):

Use load balancer with [sticky sessions](https://www.imperva.com/learn/availability/sticky-session-persistence-and-cookies/) if you can (from business point of view) partition 'by client'
[image]

Answer (score -1):

you question looks more like an architecture question.
As a start, I would have a look into  the [Kie Execution Server](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.73.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/#_ch.kie.server) component provided with Drools that helps you to create microservice decisions  based on Drools rulesets.

[Kie Execution Server](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.73.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/#_ch.kie.server) (used in stateless mode by clients) could be embedded in different pods/instances/servers to ensure horizontal scalability.

As mentioned by @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas , one of the problem you'll face will be the simultaneous hot deploy of new rulesets on the "swarm" of kieserver that hosts your services.

That would have to be handled using a proper devops strategy.

Best

Emmanuel

Comment: For cloud native Drools it is better to look at Kogito https://kogito.kie.org/. Kie Server is legacy.